# what is the security risk when enabling directory listing in linux web servers

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a few folders in which i did not have any index.htm or index.php and i dont want to have one so that i can see all the html files in that. I dont have other extensions other than .htm in those folders.

What will be the security risk in having directory listing enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security risk is such that users can see whats in that directory and if that directory has other directories below it.

Some PCI security scanners will detect directory indexing as a security issue because malicious users could potentially work out what file structure you are using, which system and even sometimes which web script if you use one and use that info to launch an attack - this risk is generally classified as low though